# Teamcity adjust dependency chains depending on VCS Trigger Rules

Tags: teamcity

Is it possible to run dependency builds depending on trigger rules?
For example We have 'Derived' project that is derived from 'Base' project under one solution.
I need to adjust:

- if someone commits changes in "solution/Base...": Run build for Base as well as Derived build configurations
- if changes was only in Derived folder: Run "solution/Derived" - disable dependency on Base and build just Derived.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "dependency": you don't seem to be using, or talking about, TeamCity "snapshot dependencies" or "artifact dependencies" here. Are you? What is the dependency in your case? Do you simply mean that one project "depends" on one VCS area, and the other depends on another?

Comment: snapshot dependency.

Comment: Does Base snapshot-depend on Derived? Or vice versa? Must they depend on each other?

Comment: Derived depend on Base ( it is logically ). Changes in Base should build Base and Derived ( it can be achieved by adding Build Finish Trigger rule on derived, but in this case it should be on same agent, snapshot dependency should be on Derived from Base). In this case - if changes only in Derived - as I have snapshot dependency from Base - firstly builds Base - and I don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

When defining the snapshot dependency at Derived (which depends on Base), check the "Do not run new build if there is a suitable one" checkbox.

Comment: Yes, I resolve this problem, but initially I should specify checkout rules. Because later both projects watched to the same parent folder 'solution', and 'Do not run new build if there is a suitable one' didn't work.